# Failed to obtain external Linaro toolchain version error

Tags: yocto, bitbake, linaro, arago

I am trying to build rootfs with Yocto-Arago SDK and get `Failed to obtain external Linaro toolchain version` error.

```
ERROR: Failed to obtain external Linaro toolchain version: Execution of '/opt/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.7-2013.03-20130313_linux/bin/INVALID-oe-linux-gcc -v' failed: command not found
ERROR: Failed to obtain external Linaro toolchain version: Execution of '/opt/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.7-2013.03-20130313_linux/bin/INVALID-oe-linux-gcc -v' failed: command not found
```

There obviously should be `TARGET_PREFIX` on place of `INVALID-oe-linux`. 
I have tied to export it before bitbake run, without success. How it heppen to be set to this value?

Comment: One of bitbake approach assumes to clean enviroment variables - to be independent, but it's doesn't mean that You are not able to pass some external variables to build environment - [here](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#parsing-the-base-configuration-metadata). But I recommend You to figure out where and how this binary file, firstly find which recipe is provide/generate this file and lately e.g. with using _$ bitbake -e task &> log1_ where it's configured.

Comment: please check INVALID-oe-linux-gcc -v' why its showingg INAVALID. you missed the variable in the palce of INVALID maybe.